# Binding in ItemTemplate in ResourceDictionary

Tags: xaml, binding, datatemplate, microsoft-metro, resourcedictionary

I'm working on a C++ Metro style app and have a problem with the binding inside an ItemTemplate of a ListView (or its items respectively). If I do it right in my Page.xaml it is working. The (simplified) code would be:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="m_listParts" ItemsSource="{Binding PartsList}>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="60" Height="60">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Part}"/>
                </Grid>                      
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

However, I would like to have the ItemTemplate definition in my resourceDictionary. But I cannot figure out how to get the binding working. It just seems to not find the bound properties anymore.

Here is my (simplified) try (since the ItemsPanel is working I suppose I loaded the dictionary itself properly):

```xml
<Style x:Key="PartsListListView" TargetType="ListView">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="60" Height="60">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Part}"/>
                    </Grid>                       
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>     
</Style>
```

The PartsList is an observable vector holding PartViewItem objects which consists of a Part property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write your Xaml as

```
<ListView 
    ItemsPanel="{StaticResource MyItemsPanel}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}" .../>
```

where you have resources

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="MyItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type MyItemType}">
     <StackPanel ....
  </DataTemplate>

  <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="MyItemsPanel">
     <StackPanel...
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: I wasn't fully aware of how to place these templates. So thanks!